# Linear interpolation in Python but using column titles as index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-interpolation

I have a dataframe with missing values that I need to interpolate horizontally across columns. For the interpolation, the names of some columns (the names are numeric) are to be used as the index values for the interpolation. I have put together the following example to better communicate the issue:

Initial dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
testdata1 = [('Prod', ['P1', 'P2']),
 ('A', ['1', '1']),
 ('1', ['10', '40']),
 ('2', ['', '']),
 ('3', ['30', '80']),
 ('B', ['1', '2']),             
 ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(testdata1)
df
```

[image: Initial df]

Target dataframe:

```
targetdf = [('Prod', ['P1', 'P2']),
 ('A', ['1', '1']),
 ('1', ['10', '40']),
 ('2', ['20', '60']),
 ('3', ['30', '80']),
 ('B', ['1', '2']),             
 ]
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(targetdf)
df2
```

[image: Target df]

In my example above, the columns to perform interpolation (horizontally) on are columns '1', '2' and '3'. And those column titles (1, 2 and 3) are the index values to be used in the interpolation calculation.

I know how to use .interpolate() in Python but only when the index values are all cells in one particular column.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with parameter `axis=1` for process by rows:

```
#replace whitespaces to NaNs
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
#rename columns from strings to number
d = {'1':1,'2':2,'3':3}
df = df.rename(columns=d)
#columns for interploate (necessary numeric)
cols = [1,2,3]

#convert values in cols to floats first, interpolate and if int output convert to int last
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)
                   .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method='index'), axis=1)
                   .astype(int)
print (df)
  Prod  A   1   2   3  B
0   P1  1  10  20  30  1
1   P2  1  40  60  80  2
```

Comment: I have a question. Please where did you specify the Index values to be used for the interpolation? I know you used the index method but I cant understand where you specified values to use for the index.

Comment: It use columns names, `1,2,3`. the best is check it by `df[cols].astype(float).apply(f, axis=1)` and `def f(x): print (x) print (interpolate(method='index')`

Comment: rows are converted to `Series` and indexes are columns names, because `apply(axis=1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the column names are numeric, but they're listed as strings in the example data you provided.  If they're actually numeric types, `interpolate()` should just work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

testdata1 = [('Prod', ['P1', 'P2']),
             ('A', [1., 1.]),
             (1, [10., 40.]),
             (2, [np.nan, np.nan]),
             (3, [30., 80.]),
             ('B', [1., 2.]),             
            ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(testdata1)

cols = [1,2,3]
df[cols] = df[cols].interpolate(method="index", axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Prod    A     1     2     3    B
0   P1  1.0  10.0  20.0  30.0  1.0
1   P2  1.0  40.0  60.0  80.0  2.0
```

Comment: Hi Andrew. I can't get it to work when i changed Column name '2' to '2.2'

Comment: Hi Jdoe, I just checked on my end, changing column from `2` to `2.2` still performs the interpolation correctly.  Can you confirm that you updated `cols` to `[1,2.2,3]` as well?  Also, can you confirm that the column name is actually `2.2` and not the string representation, i.e. `"2.2"`?

Comment: Hi Andrew. For some reason, it's not working for me. Getting the following error:

TypeError: Cannot interpolate with all NaNs.

Comment: I think you may have some of your values defined as strings.  Jezrael's answer takes care of this nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to numeric and apply `interpolate`

```
In [104]: cols = ['1','2','3']

In [105]: df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric).interpolate(axis=1)
Out[105]:
      1     2     3
0  10.0  20.0  30.0
1  40.0  60.0  80.0
```

Comment: Hi John. I can't get it to work when i changed Column name '2' to '2.2'